# Validation attribute doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am working in asp.net web api project. I created a ValidationAttribute class like as

```
public class MyValidationAttribute: ValidationAttribute
{
    private int _Id { get; set; }
    public MyValidationAttribute(int Id)
    {
        _Id = Id;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        object abc = value;
        if (_Id > 10)
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        return base.IsValid(value, validationContext);
    }
}
```

After that I am using this on a function

```
[MyValidationAttribute(12)]
public object MyFunction(int Iden){
//Some code here
}
```

The issue is, on debug mode, I can see that control is not parsing the MyValidationAttribute class. Am I doing some thing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Data attributes are supposed to be used on properties.

Change it to the following instead:

```
[MyValidationAttribute(12)]
public int MyProperty { get; set; }
```